# How to combine 2 arrays that have the same index and value with php?

Tags: php, arrays, yii2, frameworks

I have 2 array like follows:

```
$array1 = [
 '0' => [
   'no_invoice' => 'INV0001',
   'product_code' => '1111111',
  ], 
 '1' => [
  'no_invoice' => 'INV0001',
  'product_code' => '1111112',
 ]
];

  $array2 = [
    '0' => [
      'product_code' => '1111112',
      'free_valie' => 839,
      'count' => 1240
    ],
  ];
```

Is it possible to combine arrays above to be like this:

```
Array(
 [0] => Array
  (
    'no_invoice' => 'INV0001',
    'product_code' => '1111111',
  )
 [1] => Array
  (
    'no_invoice' => 'INV0001',
    'product_code' => '1111112',
    'free_valie' => 839,
    'count' => 1240
  )
)
```

So, if array have same product code, then it will join like the example above.

I have been tried with use array merge, `array_merge($array1, $array2)`;
But the result is like this:

```
Array(
 [0] => Array
  (
    'no_invoice' => 'INV0001',
    'product_code' => '1111111',
  )
 [1] => Array
  (
    'no_invoice' => 'INV0001',
    'product_code' => '1111112',
  )
 [2] => Array
  (
    'product_code' => '1111112',
    'free_valie' => 839,
    'count' => 1240
  )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will do what you want. It loops over each value in `$array1`, using [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to see if the entrie's `product_code` is also present in `$array2` (by looking through the `product_code` column of `$array2` extracted using [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)). If it is, the values are merged. Note that we use `&$val` in the foreach, causing the value to be passed by reference which allows it to be modified in the loop

```
foreach ($array1 as &$val) {
    if (($k = array_search($val['product_code'], array_column($array2, 'product_code'))) !== false) {
        $val = array_merge($val, $array2[$k]);
    }
}

print_r($array1);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [no_invoice] => INV0001
            [product_code] => 1111111
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [no_invoice] => INV0001
            [product_code] => 1111112
            [free_valie] => 839
            [count] => 1240
        )

)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/XXJs3)

Comment: May i know, why should be given & on &val ?
What does it mean &val ?

Comment: That indicates that the value is being passed by reference, which allows it to be modified in the loop. If you try the code without the `&` you'll see that it doesn't modify `$array1`

Answer (score 2):

Try below one.

```
$array1 = [
    '0' => [
        'no_invoice'   => 'INV0001',
        'product_code' => '1111111',
    ],
    '1' => [
        'no_invoice'   => 'INV0001',
        'product_code' => '1111112',
    ]
];

$array2 = [
    '0' => [
        'product_code' => '1111112',
        'free_valie'   => 839,
        'count'        => 1240
    ],
];

foreach ($array1 as $key => &$value) {
    $key = array_search($value['product_code'], array_column($array2, 'product_code'));
    if ($key !== false) {
        $value  = array_merge($value, $array2[$key]);
        unset($array2[$key]);
        $array2 = array_values($array2);
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array1);
exit;
```

Comment: How is this any different from the answer I posted?

Comment: Looks like no difference except unset the matched array.